# GraphQl doesn't authorize using JWT token

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-django

I am following this blog tutorial...well so far so good and i am generating then token...using GraphQl's default template

```
input->

   mutation{
    tokenAuth(username:"riyad", password:"1234"){
    token
     }
  }
 
output-> 

   {
  "data": {
    "tokenAuth": {
      "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InJpeWFkIiwiZXhwIjoxNTkzNTI0Nzk5LCJvcmlnX2lhdCI6MTU5MzUyNDQ5OX0.DjploWeEwLpRBZX0wz5_NSqz22qDHbgNI26uXs6fuXE"
              }
          }
      }
```

but when i am fetching using insominia i am not getting the user authorize....rather it raise exception that i created...
[image: Post Request]

[image: Header Token Added]

my schema file ->

```
class UserType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()


class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    me = graphene.Field(UserType)
    users = graphene.List(UserType)

    def resolve_users(self, info, **kwargs):
        return get_user_model().objects.all()

    def resolve_me(self, info):
        user = info.context.user
        if user.is_anonymous:
            raise Exception('Not logged in!')

        return user
```

my settings.file that i extra added

```
GRAPHENE = {
    'SCHEMA': 'hackernews.schema.schema'
}

'''python(path=“…/graphql-python/hackernews/hackernews/settings.py”) GRAPHENE = { ‘SCHEMA’: ‘mysite.myschema.schema’, ‘MIDDLEWARE’: [ ‘graphql_jwt.middleware.JSONWebTokenMiddleware’, ], } '''

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'graphql_jwt.backends.JSONWebTokenBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]
```

my main app ->

```
import graphene
import links.schema
import users.schema
import graphql_jwt


class Query(users.schema.Query, links.schema.Query, graphene.ObjectType):
    pass


class Mutation(users.schema.Mutation, links.schema.Mutation, graphene.ObjectType):
    token_auth = graphql_jwt.ObtainJSONWebToken.Field()
    verify_token = graphql_jwt.Verify.Field()
    refresh_token = graphql_jwt.Refresh.Field()


schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, mutation=Mutation)
```

Comment: https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-python/4-authentication/
the blog i mentioned far above to the first line

Answer (score 1):

i solved it by moving

```
'MIDDLEWARE': [ 'graphql_jwt.middleware.JSONWebTokenMiddleware', ],
```

which is inside the GRAPHENE variable in the settings.py file to inside the MIDDLEWARE variable in the same file.

reference --> https://github.com/howtographql/howtographql/issues/983